# gauge$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] Exploits

Tags: php, forms

> However, consider that a user enters the following URL in the address bar:
>
> http://www.example.com/test_form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
>
> In this case, the above code will be translated to:

`<form method="post" action="test_form.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>`

My question is that what is that part starting "%22%3E%"? is it a kind of language? and how that is translated to the the above script code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%22%3E%` is the encoded rendering of `"><`.
What this snippet demonstrates is how appending content to a URL string may inject content into your html page if PHP (or any other server-side scripting language, for that matter) is used carelessly.

Here, all it does is inject some javascript to pop up an alert window (`<script>alert('hacked')</script>`). Potentially, it could have injected javascript code with a much more malicious effect.

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by encoded rendering? u mean it is translated by the browser html engine?

Comment: This is the **http** representation (used to allow special characters in the URL). So it isn't translate  by the **html** engine, but yes, you have the right idea.